# Excel formula for calculating product cost

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to calculate product cost based on the price and quantity in Excel

[image]

I have used the formula for

Product 1 - =(B2 * C2)/1000 + (B3 * C3)/1000 + (B4 * C4)/1000  + (B5 * C5)/1000

Product 2 - =(B2 * C2)/1000 + (B3 * C3)/1000 + (B4 * C4)/1000  + (B5 * C5)/1000

But the problem is if I add one more product, drag drop formula is not working.

**Any better way to handle this?**

Comment: **drag drop formula is not working**: this comment doesn't tell us anything about your issue. When you say that, what do you mean? does it throw an error? if so, whats the error? Or it runs but doesn't give the an answer or even gives an unexpected answer.. please elaborate on the issue

Comment: what do you mean by "add one more product" is that another row?

Comment: Yes: `=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$B5,C2:C5)/1000`

Comment: Two remarks: both your formulas are equal (at first sight) and second: your formulas mention column letters and row numbers, but those are not visible from your screenshot. Can you show a screenshot where that information is visible (don't add another screenshot, but replace the current one)?

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ, thank you. Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a dynamic range in ready for the product additional rows

In C6, formula copied right to D6 :

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(9^9,$B:$B))*C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(9^9,$B:$B)))/1000
```

[image]